# invalid syntax, на что ругается?

Tags: python

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

print("Задаем N")
N=int(input())
summ=[]
sum1=0
for x in np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.01):   
      for k in range(0,N+1):
        sum1+=(np.cos((2*k-1)*x)/((2*k-1)*(2*k-1))
    sum1 = (np.pi/2)-(4/(np.pi))*sum1  
    summ.append(sum1)
    sum1=0          

x=np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.01)
y=np.fabs(x)
plt.title("Графики")
plt.xlabel("Ось Х")
plt.ylabel("Ось Y")
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(x,y,'r',label='|x|')
plt.plot(x,summ1,'b',label='Ряд Фурье')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-9-f5eaa5d07c6e>", line 8
>     sum1 = (np.pi/2)-(4/(np.pi))*sum1
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Сравните число открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок в предыдущей строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum1+=(np.cos((2*k-1)*x)/((2*k-1)*(2*k-1))`
Не закрыта скобка